# Cakephp CMS Tutorial PaginatorComponent is deprecated, throws warnings

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

The Content Management Tutorial at cakephp throws deprecation errors concerning the paginator.

This code is the source for the warning.

```
<?php
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find());
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }
```

It generates the warning
`Deprecated (16384) : PaginatorComponent is deprecated, use a Cake\Datasource\Pagination\NumericPaginator instance directly. /home/..../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ComponentRegistry.php, line: 133`

Found two hints to change the source. Remove the loadComponent and change the pagination method.

```
<?php
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }

    public function index()
    {
    // Paginate the ORM table.
    $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($this->Articles));
    }
```

Background for pagination 4.x [cakephp doc pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/pagination.html)

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: No question anymore; I found the solution after trying different approaches, but as it is an error in the official tutorial and nowhere is a solution explained, i thought i would post it.